# JavaScript onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
area = document.createElement('div');
drag = document.createElement('div');
body.appendChild(area);
area.appendChild(drag);

area.onmouseover = function () {
    console.log('entered');
}
area.onmouseout = function () {
    console.log('leaved');
}
```

The problem is that when mouse goes over the child drag it counts as enter and leave!

Preview:
http://s12.postimage.org/xopqous19/preview.gif

Comment: Can I ask what program you used to make that image?

Comment: The image looks all dark. LOL

Comment: preview.gif ain't workin. try using imgur to upload your gif next time.

also! jsfiddle.net plz

Comment: @HanletEscaño , MicronXD i will upload it on youtube

Comment: @Bahaazahika: Instead of YouTube, try to make an example at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` instead, which don't suffer from the *bubble* effect.

jQuery has a **cross-browser** version of both, called [`mousenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Else, you can refer to [this](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/) for another cross-browser implementation, which doesn't rely on external libraries.

Comment: i don't want to use jquery for some reason.
and onmouseenter and onmouseleave on work for IE

Comment: @Bahaazahika: Refer to this implementation then: http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/.

Comment: its work with IE but not with chrome and others error:Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLUListElement> has no method 'attachEvent'

Comment: @Bahaazahika: Yes, `onmouseenter` is IE-specific. For a cross-browser version either use `jQuery` or the implementation in that site.